# Can the cleanup function within useEffect be used to prevent unmounting of the component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to display an unsaved changes popup when the user attempts to navigate away from the component. The functionality I am looking for is similar to the `window.confirm` popup.

I have a function to invoke the popup from the cleanup in `useEffect`, something similar to [this](https://akashhamirwasia.com/blog/building-expressive-confirm-dialog-api-in-react/) but returning false does not seem to be preventing the unmount.

Comment: Try [prompt](https://v5.reactrouter.com/core/api/Prompt) if you use react-router

Comment: maybe you could try to add a state inside the parent component to conditionally render this component, and lift up the handler to open the popup as well